# Game Center doesn't accept my code after I updated to Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, game-center

This is my code:

```
if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {
            if mode == 60 {
                var scoreReporter2 = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "countrymaster60") //leaderboard id here

                scoreReporter2.value = Int64(score) //score variable here (same as above)
                var scoreArray: [GKScore] = [scoreReporter2]
                GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: {(error : NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error")
                    }
```

The error message it gives:

> Cannot invoke 'reportScores' with an argument list of type
>   '([GKScore], withCompletionHandler: (NSError!) -> Void)'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says that the method signature is:

```
class func reportScores(_ scores: [GKScore], withCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((NSError?) -> Void)?)
```

So you need to make the `error` variable in the completion handler an Optional.

Change

```
GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: {(error : NSError!) -> Void in
```

for

```
GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: {(error : NSError?) -> Void in
```